# Setting the sku name and tier of Azure ARM template serverfarm

Tags: json, azure

We are creating a deployment template using Azure resource manager.  We have virtually everything set up however the created hostplan does not pick up the correct pricing tier.  No matter what values we use it always seems to default to the 'Free' 'F1' pricing plan.

Here is the section

```
{
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "name": "[variables('sitePlanName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "B1",
            "tier": "Basic",
            "capacity": 1
        },
        "properties": {
            "numberOfWorkers": 1
        }
    },
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I am having a similar problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 8):

Can you try to specify the SKU inside the "properties" node of the serverfarms description, something like that :

```
{
  "apiVersion":"2015-08-01",
  "name":"[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
  "type":"Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties":{
    "name":"[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
    "sku":"Basic",
    "workerSize":"1"
    "numberOfWorkers":1
  }
}
```

Possible values for "sku" are : Free, Shared, Basic, Standard, Premium

For Basic, Standard and Premium SKUs, the "workerSize" possible values could be 0 (small), 1 (medium) or 2 (large) :

```
"sku": {
    "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "Free",
            "Shared",
            "Basic",
            "Standard",
            "Premium"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "Free"
    },
    "workerSize": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "0",
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "0"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Julien

Comment: Where did you get this list of possible values?

Answer (score 6):

Try with this resource block (works for me) to create S1 instance:

```
  {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
        "workerSize": "0",
        "numberOfWorkers": 1
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "S1",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "size": "S1",
        "family": "S",
        "capacity": "1"
      }
    }
```

For basic Tier use this sku:

```
"sku": {
        "name": "B1",
        "tier": "Basic",
        "size": "B1",
        "family": "B",
        "capacity": 1
      }
```